# Filtering & deleting recurring data in table - SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL, One contains grand total per line item (master table) and another that contains selling price & item detail per line item (Sub Table). The hopes to join both tables together but yet only return total sum price based on each product and its price.  The query would delete any recurring data in the master table

[Master Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3tTB.png)

[Sub table with Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6oEm.png)

[The Outcome looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GjGA.png)

Comment: please include what you have tried so we can help you with actual viable changes using the actual entities

Comment: delete Master 
from Master as t
 inner join subtableas u on u.sequence = t.sequence
where t.sequence <> u.rrank

Comment: Edit your post and add any requested information to it. And it is far better to include a script or fiddle that contains DDL, sample data. and the desired results based on that sample data. No one should need to guess about your schema, the datatypes it uses, the relationships (foreign keys) between the tables, the keys (primary and natural), etc. And shame on a database designer who chooses names like "Master" and "subtables"!

Answer (score 0):

```
-- create table
CREATE TABLE TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (
    id int IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    ShipmentId int NULL,
    TotalPrice bigint NULL,
    CONSTRAINT MasterTable_PK PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- insert sample data 
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 2250);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 2250);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 2250);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 2250);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 2250);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 2250);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 2250);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 2250);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 2250);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 2250);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 0);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 16500);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 16500);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES( 5758, 16500);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 0);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 6000);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 6000);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 6000);
INSERT INTO TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable (ShipmentId, TotalPrice) VALUES(5758, 0);



-- deleting all dublicates 
declare 
@del_count integer; 

set @del_count = 1; 

while @del_count > 0
begin
    
    delete from TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable 
    where id in 
    (
        select min(id) from TEST_DB.dbo.MasterTable
        group by ShipmentId, TotalPrice
        having count(*) > 1
    );
    set @del_count = @@ROWCOUNT;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an update-able CTE for this

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY ShipmentId, TotalPrice ORDER BY id)
    FROM MasterTable
)
DELETE cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided the what i have tried query you supplied is the right way to spot what to delete, presumably first row is equal any any later gets an increment or something?

```
delete from Master 
where Id in (
    select t.Id
    from Master as t 
    inner join subtable as u 
    on u.sequence = t.sequence 
    where t.sequence <> u.rrank 
          and exists(select top(1) b.sequence from subtable b where b.sequence == t.sequence and rrank = t.sequence)
)
```

Comment: This is close to what I was getting before and failed, but it still missing the pear from the list which is at price of 0.00. If you check the image. it has five items on it, two unique items at 0.00 and 3 unique items at different prices https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GjGA.png

Comment: Oh i presumed how to delete was your problem and accepted your subquery direct, will update, your presumption that rrnk exists doesn't hold, this is why we'll have to require it in expression in that case

Comment: @user17384043 so with the update do you have a solve?